# How to isolate tests using flask-pymongo, pymongo MongoClient() and pytest?

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pytest

EDIT: pymongo 4.3.3; python 3.10.12; flask-pymongo 2.3.0; pytest 7.3.1

Need help with Flask-PyMongo integration tests to simulate MongoDB being down. Tests are affected by the order of execution and fixture use. Looking for ways to isolate tests and control MongoDB availability.

I am writing integration tests for the case when Mongo IS available, and for when Mongo is NOT available. The tests are:

```
<other imports>
from app.app import app_module

def test_available(app_instance):
    assert app_module.check_mongodb_availability(app_instance) == True

def test_unavailable():
    test_app = app_module.create_app({'MONGO_URI': 'mongodb://invalid_uri:27017'})
    result = app_module.check_mongodb_availability(test_app)
    assert result is False
```

My `environment_setup()` fixture spins up a mongodb container and the containerized flask app (with a `session` scope) for testing `test_available()` among other test functions. So in the `test_unavailable()` function, I create the app instance and pass in an invalid mongo URI with the intention of simulating an unavailable mongodb.

The problem is that if I use my `mongo_client()` fixture at ANY time preceding `test_unavailable()` it will unexpectedly fail:

```
def test_nothing(mongo_client):
    assert True

def test_unavailable(): 
    ...
```

And if I don't use `mongo_client()` at any time preceding these tests, `test_available()` fails.

But if I prevent the mongo container from being spun up in the first place (sanity check), `test_unavailable()` passes, but clearly this breaks my other tests.

These tests shouldn't have anything to do with the `mongo_client()` but clearly they are affected.

Note: I have tried multiple ways of closing the mongo client. I have also tried closing the mongo.ctx instance from within the flask app instance.

**Context:**

The relevant code of the Flask app is:

```
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo 
from pymongo.errors import ConnectionFailure 
<other imports>

mongo = PyMongo()

def check_mongodb_availability(app: Flask, max_retries: int = 5, delay: int = 2) -> bool:
    for attempt in range(max_retries): 
        try: with app.app_context():             
            mongo.db.command('ping') 
            return True 
        except ConnectionFailure: 
            time.sleep(delay) 
    return False

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # Setup 
    app = Flask(name, instance_relative_config=True)
    settings = AppSettings()
    app.config['MONGO_URI'] = settings.get('mongo_uri')
    <other configs>

    # Apply test config if provided
    if test_config:
        app.config.update(test_config)
    
    # Initialize Pymongo
    mongo.init_app(app)
    
    <routes>
    
    return app
```

The relevant pieces of the conftest.py file looks like:

```
<other imports>
import pytest
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from pymongo import MongoClient

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def setup_environment():

    # Set the mongo uri as an environment variable
    <read in params to build mongo uri>
    os.environ['MONGO_URI'] = f"mongodb://{uname}:{pword}@localhost:{port}/{db}

    # Run the flask and mongo services
    subprocess.run(<spins up flask and mongodb docker containers>)

    yield

    # Clean up
    os.environ.pop('MONGO_URI', None)
    subprocess.run(<tears down flask and mongodb docker containers>)

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def mongo_client(setup_environemnt, directConnection=True): 
    # Note: I tried directConnection=False as well

    mongo_uri = os.environ['MONGO_URI']
    client = MongoClient(mongo_uri)
    try:
        yield client
    finally:
        client.close()

@pytest.fixture(scope='function')
def app_instance(request):
    from app.app import create_app
    return create_app()

<more fixtures for app context and app client>
```

Please help me understand why I am failing to isolate my tests and how i can fix it.